# How to create HTML image links in Outlook proportional to the viewing window?

Tags: html, outlook

So I'm not the greatest HTML programmer but I've recently been tasked to create an HTML email that contains image links. My goal is to have the images rescale proportional to the browser size so that the images aren't too big when viewing them on mobile but don't look too small when viewing them in a browser/Outlook.

Here is the line I used to generate the links:

```
<a href="[link goes here]"><img alt="title" width="5%" height="9%" src="[picture goes here]" /></a>
```

This "appears" to do what I want to do. When I zoom in and out of the screen, the images stay the same size. Everything looks great when viewing from a browser but once I insert the code in Outlook 2010, the images don't keep their sizes. In fact, they go back to their original  W/H, 488x592.

I've also tried to hardcode the W/H to: `width="40" height="50"` but while it looks great on mobile, it looks tiny in a browser.

Let me know if you need further clarification or other parts of the original HTML code. Please remember this has to work on Outlook. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS media queries to do that!

```
/* before resize */
img{
    width: 600px;
}

/* after resize below 480px */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

The idea here is that once the screen size gets below 480px, you can set the image's width to whatever you'd like - this this case, 300px.

You can check it out here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I wasn't aware that Outlook supported CSS. That allows me to do more things with this email. Thanks.

So just to make sure, by adding this code, anytime the img tag is used, it will resize the image to 300 if the window is less than 480?

It will sort of work for what I need but it would be better if it was proportional because I want to account for people viewing them on large monitors as well as mobile phones and everything in between.

Comment: Well, if you want an image that changes with every single pixel, I would suggest against it. It's too hard to predict what's going to happen to the layout. Yup, that's how it works. You could add more media queries to handle the in betweens if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Checked in Outlook 2016

- CSS media queries did not work in it

Solution:

Just give the one parameter either width or height to image, it will adjust proportionally according to its parent for example:

```
<img src='{$link}'  height='125'/>
```